# Pixelated fonts in chromer Webket

Tags: css, google-chrome

[image]

The same code looks different in Chrome and Firefox. In Firefox its more sharp and clean however in Chrome, its semi bold and blurred.

Comment: Post your html/css

Comment: I must be getting old, because the bottom one looks better to me than the top one.

Comment: are you using **transform:translate(X%, Y%)** ? that is culprit in most cases